# Why won't the current page of my navigation bar stay highlighted?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, navigation

I have read very many forums and tried many different ways to make the current page of my navigation menu stay highlighted, and I can't figure out why it won't work.
I don't want to use Javascript or PHP - only CSS.

This is what I have for HTML:

```
    <body id="@ViewBag.IDTag">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "homenav" } })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("What Is EDI?", "WhatIsEDI", "Home", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "whatisedinav" } })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bills of Lading", "Index", "Bills_of_Lading", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "billsofladingnav" } })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Issues & Solutions", "Index", "Issues_and_Solutions", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "issuesandsolutionsnav" } })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Partners", "Index", "Partners", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "partnersnav" } })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Locations", "Index", "Locations", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "locationsnav" } })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Refineries", "Index", "Refineries", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "refineriesnav" } })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sources", "Index", "Sources", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "sourcesnav" } })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Transfer Criteria", "Index", "Transfer_Criteria", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "transfercriterianav" } })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Transportation Methods", "Index", "Transportation_Methods", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "transportationmethodsnav" } })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Rack to Partner Mappings", "Index", "Rack_to_Partner_Mappings", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "racktopartnermappingsnav" } })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Products", "Index", "Products", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "productsnav" } })</li>                    
        </ul>
    </body>
```

On each view, I have the id at the top of the page. An example of the home page is:

```
    @{
        ViewBag.IDTag = "home";
    }
```

This is what my CSS looks like:

```
    ul#menu             
    {
        font-size: .8em;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #FFF;
        float: left;
        width: 130px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-top: 133px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
        padding: 0; 
    }

    ul#menu a:link, ul#menu a:visited
    {
        display:block;
        font-weight:bold;
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: rgb(139,177,216);
        width: 120px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    ul#menu a:hover, ul#menu a:active
    {
        background-color: #365f87;
    }

body#home a#homenav, 
body#whatisedi a#whatisedinav,
body#billsoflading a#billsofladingnav,
body#issuesandsolutions a#issuesandsolutionsnav,
body#partners a#partnersnav, 
body#locations a#locationsnav, 
body#refineries a#refineriesnav,
body#sources a#sourcesnav,
body#transfercriteria a#transfercriterianav,
body#transportationmethods a#transportationmethodsnav,
body#racktopartnermappings a#racktopartnermappingsnav,
body#products a#productsnav     
{
    background-color: #365f87;          /* highlights current page */
    text-transform: lowercase;
    cursor:default;
}
```

I'm new to all of this, so it could simply be an syntax issue, or calling something "body" when it should be "div" or "id" when it should be "class". I am at the point where nothing I have tried makes a single difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to put a space between `body` and `#` otherwise you are saying a body tag with and id of all those strings after `#`. IMO I would just add a single class to the current nav element.

Comment: Adding the space didn't change anything.  What do you mean by adding a single class to the current nav element?

Comment: Take a look at the link I posted as an answer. It is a better way to handle this situation.

Comment: Okay - apparently it was the space that fixed everything. Weird. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the method used on this question. It makes the process more dynamic and you write less code.

[Adding "active" tag to navigation list in an asp.net mvc master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214583/adding-active-tag-to-navigation-list-in-an-asp-net-mvc-master-page)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an active class to your `<li>`.  I don't know `asp.net` but as you're dynamically setting the id for the  `<body>` I would think something like this would work:

My PHP version

```
// with a function

function is_active_li( bodyID, identifier ) {
     echo identifier == bodyID ? 'active' : '';
}

<li class="<?php is_active_li( $bodyID, 'home'); ?>">Home</li>
<li class="<?php is_active_li( $bodyID, 'whatisedi'); ?>">Home</li>
<li class="<?php is_active_li( $bodyID, 'billsoflading'); ?>">Home</li>

// or all inline

<li class="<?php echo 'homev' == bodyID ? 'active' : ''; ?>">Home</li>
<li class="<?php echo 'whatisedi' == bodyID ? 'active' : ''; ?>">Home</li>
<li class="<?php echo 'billsoflading' == bodyID ? 'active' : ''; ?>">Home</li>
```