# Navigation tab stay a certain color

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am using ASP.net and have a master page that utilizes navigation. My problem is when I click on a link it loads a different asp page, but the navigation tab doesn't switch to the clicked color,it reverts back to its original color. Since all the pages are loading the same, I can't just use CSS because the page is reloaded. Is there a way to write a javascript function that tells the page when it loads to display the hover color and keep it there? Since the only HTML I use is on the master page, I can't switch anything out. I'm sure there must be a way using nth-child but I can't figure it out. As for the code, a simple example is:

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <li>One</li>
     <li>Two</li>
     <li>Three</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

So how would I get the 2nd link to switch to the hover color when loading the page?

Comment: How much of the code do you control?  While it's not really hard to access the second `<li>`, it would be much easier if you could have `<li id="secondLink">Two</li>`.

Comment: You should set class to currently opened page's `li`, which could be seen differently. You can do that using Server Side Script or JavaScript.

Comment: Try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214583/adding-active-tag-to-navigation-list-in-an-asp-net-mvc-master-page

Comment: I can't add the <li id="secondLink"> Two</li> since it effects every page

Comment: @Keith Sorry, to be more clear - do you have control over the master page?  Can you add ids to all the links in the navigation tab of the master page?  It's alright (and probably desirable) to have those ids be everywhere.  Alternatively, since this is asp, do the `<li>`s already have a name attribute?

Comment: Yeah i have control over masterpage

Comment: The problem this is I have to write something that will override its natural state since everything is being implemented the same

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've played with asp, so I won't have the exact terms, but I can point you in the right direction.

First, in your master page, add unique ids to all of your nav links.  This will make it trivial to access those links in your specific asp pages.  It helps to do this because otherwise it's hard to select the link you want.  jQuery such as `$("div ul li:nth-child('2')")` will select the second `li` that's a child of a `ul` that's a child of `div`, but that could happen anywhere on your page.

Once you have that, let's assume your nav panel looks like this:

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <li id="linkOne">One</li>
     <li id="linkTwo">Two</li>
     <li id="linkThree">Three</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Then, in the page that loads when Two is clicked, you need to add a script with an onLoad handler that modifies the link:

```
<script>
    document.onload = function() { $("#linkTwo").addClass("hover"); };
</script>
```

This will wait till the document loads (otherwise you may try changing an element that doesn't exist yet), then run a function that finds the specific element with the id "linkTwo" and adds the css class "hover" to it.

Obviously, this line will be different for each specific asp page - or something you can have your server-side logic calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear. But if i understood right in your case i should use a specific css class that is loaded if you determine that you are on current page.

Something like this (i don't know asp, i will put a general example)

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <li <?php if($CurrentPage = 'One') {echo 'class="active"';} ?>>One</li>
     <li <?php if($CurrentPage = 'Two') {echo 'class="active"';} ?> >Two</li>
     <li <?php if($CurrentPage = 'Three') {echo 'class="active"';} ?>>Three</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

this will put a special class to your element. That class will have the hover color, and the problem is solved.
Hope you can adapt this to asp.

Answer (score 0):

## Use the following:

### html code

```
<body>
    <div>
       <ul style="display:inline; background-color:lightgray; float:left">
         <li style="margin:20px; display:inline-block" onclick="frames['target'].location.href='one.html'; toggle_bgcolor(this);">One</li>
         <li style="margin:20px; display:inline-block" onclick="frames['target'].location.href='two.html'; toggle_bgcolor(this);">Two</li>
         <li style="margin:20px; display:inline-block" onclick="frames['target'].location.href='three.html'; toggle_bgcolor(this);">Three</li>
       </ul>
       <iframe id="target"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

### JS function

```
function toggle_bgcolor(elem)
{
    for(var c=0; c<elem.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('li').length; c++)
    {
        elem.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('li')[c].style.backgroundColor='';
    }
    elem.style.backgroundColor='limegreen';
}
```

The **JS-block** for the `onclick` event in each `<li>` element will toggle the **`baclkground-color`** of each `<li>` element when another `<li>` is clicked.

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g2p6/)**